# Can't view pictures from Samsung S3

Tags: samsung, file-sharing

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. I plugged my Samsung S3 into the laptop to see files on it however, I can't view the JPG images.

How can I view pictures from my S3?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: Also, did you set up smartphone into _USB sharing_ mode?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could copy them first locally and then view them.
I think it is an MTP bug. I really hate this protocol.
I have also tested this in 14.04, same bug, i can copy them but not view them locally.